# Apply transforms to XML attribute containing escaped HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <issue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <comment text="&lt;div class=&quot;wiki text&quot;&gt;&lt;h4&gt;Tom Fenech&lt;/h4&gt;Here is a comment&lt;/div&gt;&#10;"/>
    </issue>
</root>
```

As you can see, the `text` attribute in the `comment` node contains escaped HTML. I would like to get the contents of the attribute as XHTML, which I currently do this inside a template using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

That gets me the HTML in the final output:

```
<div class="wiki text"><h4>Tom Fenech</h4>Here is a comment</div>
```

But I want to be able to extract the contents of the `<h4>` tag to use elsewhere. In general, it would be nice to be able to manipulate the contents of this once it has been escaped.

How do I apply further templates to the output of the `<xsl:value-of />`?

I am currently using the [PHP built-in XSLT processor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php), which supports XSLT version 1.0, although I would be willing to consider using an alternative processor if features from newer versions make this possible.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? Saxon 9.6 HE edition is an XSLT 3.0 processor that would allow you to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(@text)/node()"/>` or perhaps better `<xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(@text)/node()"/>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml. If you want to make use of `value-of` and `disable-output-escaping` then you always need two stylesheets, the first which outputs the attribute value using `disable-output-escaping` and the second which consumes the result of the first.

Comment: @Martin I'm using the XSLT processor that comes with PHP (which supports only version 1.0). I've updated the question. I understand that it is possible to use other XSLT processors (such as Saxon) with PHP, so I would still be interested in solutions that used features from more modern versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, by calling into a PHP function from XSLT:

```
function parseHTMLString($html)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    return $doc;
}

$xml = <<<EOB
<root>
    <issue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <comment text="&lt;div class=&quot;wiki text&quot;&gt;&lt;h4&gt;Tom Fenech&lt;/h4&gt;Here is a comment&lt;/div&gt;&#10;"/>
    </issue>
</root>
EOB;

$xsl = <<<EOB
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
     xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="comment">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="php:functionString('parseHTMLString', @text)//div/h4"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div/h4">
   <h2><xsl:apply-templates/></h2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->loadXML($xml);

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions('parseHTMLString');
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

Comment: Impressive, thanks! There were a couple of changes to make it work - I had to add `xsl:extension-element-prefixes="php"` to the opening tag and change the syntax of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply templates to unparsed (escaped or CDATA) text. See some previous answers that may be relevant to you:

[Parsing html with xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936729/parsing-html-with-xslt/23938058#23938058)

[XSLT: Reading a param that's an xml document passed as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767097/xslt-reading-a-param-thats-an-xml-document-passed-as-a-string/23768464#23768464)

[how to parse the xml inside CDATA of another xml using xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508513/how-to-parse-the-xml-inside-cdata-of-another-xml-using-xslt/14512924#14512924)

Comment: Thanks for the links - I suspected that this may not be possible in XSLT but was hoping there might be a way round it.